Webapps running on NGINX Proxy Manager still accessible in a browser using the IP and port
I'm using NGINX Proxy Manager v2.11.2.  I have installed a number of apps, but let's use linkding for the example.
Linkding and NGINX proxy manager were installed via Docker Compose.  They are on the same Docker Network called NGINX.  In the Proxy Host I have created a source called links.myserver.com (myserver is hopefully obviously not the real name.)  The destination linked is http://linkding:9090.  It's got a public certificate, I can connect to it and that works fine.
I installed Authentik for secondary authentication, and used the code in the Authentik app to do the advanced proxy work to make sure everything goes to Authentik when using links.myserver.com.  However, a big security issue I noticed was that when I type in the server's IP address and port in a web browser, I get back to the app without the Authentik authentication.  I don't think this is an Authentik issue, but rather a setup issue on my part with NGINX Proxy Manager.  I've followed a bunch of tutorials but no one addresses this.  Is there something I am doing wrong or another approach?  I tried to use UFW to block all the ports but 80, 81, 443, and 22 but it doesn't stop the web access.  I also tried to block 9090 using UFW, but I can still login.
Any suggestions here?
Thanks.
